# Alignment of single- and multi-line column headers in tabular (LaTeX)

Tags: tables

Consider the following table:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[dvips,top=1.2in,bottom=0.65in,left=1.15in,right=1.15in,includefoot]{geometry}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{p{4.2cm}p{1.5cm}p{5.5cm}p{3.25cm}}
\toprule
 \emph{\centering observed frequencies of each detection history} & \emph{\centering detections per site} & \emph{equivalent detection histories} ($h_i$) & \emph{probability} \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{1}{c} {10}&    \multicolumn{1}{c}4    &\texttt{1111}&    $\psi p^4$\\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{20}&    \multicolumn{1}{c}3    &\texttt{1110, 1101, 1011, 0111}&    $\psi p^3(1-p)$\\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{30}&\multicolumn{1}{c}2    &\texttt{1100, 1001, 1010, 0011, 0101}&     $\psi p^2(1-p)^2$\\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{20}&    \multicolumn{1}{c}1    &\texttt{1000, 0100, 0010, 0001}&    $\psi p(1-p)^3$\\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{20}&    \multicolumn{1}{c}0    &\texttt{0000}    & $\psi (1-p)^4 + (1-\psi)$\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to:

1. center the column headers (as opposed to the default left-justify), and
2. how to force single-line headers (e.g, columns 3 and 4 in example) to be aligned either in the middle, or at the bottom of the header 'cell'.

The only way I can figure out how to generate multi-line column headers is using a 'paragraph', but if I do, I can't for the life of me figure out how to center the column header text, or align it at anything other than the top.

Comment: Load `array` and use `m` rather than `p`. Assuming you want vertical centring. For horizontal, use `>{\centering\arraybackslash}` before the `m` or `p`.

Answer (score 4):

There's no real benefit to using multi-line columns when none of the rows have more than one line. In these cases, `l` and `c` are simplest.

For the others, you can use `array`'s `m{}` in place of `p{}` for vertical centring and `>{\centering\arraybackslash}` for horizontal centring. In addition, consider using `tabularx` to avoid needing to manually figure correct widths. With those in your example, the table is simply too wide for the page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\usepackage[top=1.2in,bottom=0.65in,left=1.15in,right=1.15in,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{YC{1.5cm}ll}
  \toprule
  \emph{observed frequencies of each detection history} & \emph{detections per site} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\emph{equivalent detection histories} ($h_i$)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\emph{probability}} \\
  \midrule
  10& 4 &\texttt{1111}& $\psi p^4$\\
  20& 3 &\texttt{1110, 1101, 1011, 0111}&   $\psi p^3(1-p)$\\
  30& 2 &\texttt{1100, 1001, 1010, 0011, 0101}&  $\psi p^2(1-p)^2$\\
  20& 1 &\texttt{1000, 0100, 0010, 0001}&   $\psi p(1-p)^3$\\
  20& 0 &\texttt{0000}  & $\psi (1-p)^4 + (1-\psi)$\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}    
\end{document}
```

[image: final table]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[dvips,
            top=1.2in,bottom=0.65in,left=1.15in,right=1.15in,
            includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{array,
            booktabs}
\newcommand\mch[2]{\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\itshape}b{#1}}{#2}}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c c 
                >{\ttfamily}l
                >{$}l<{$}
                }
    \toprule
\mch{3.5cm}{observed frequencies of each detection history} 
    &   \mch{1.5cm}{detections per site} 
            &   \mch{5.5cm}{equivalent detection histories ($h_i$)} 
                &   \mch{3cm}{probability}    \\
\midrule
10  &   4   &   1111                        &   \psi p^4                  \\
20  &   3   &   1110, 1101, 1011, 0111      &   \psi p^3(1-p)             \\
3   &   2   &   1100, 1001, 1010, 0011, 0101&   \psi p^2(1-p)^2           \\
20  &   1   &   1000, 0100, 0010, 0001      &   \psi p(1-p)^3             \\
20  &   0   &   0000                        &   \psi (1-p)^4 + (1-\psi)   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

width of columns is determined with new command `\mch` (you can select other name) with two arguments: first is width of column, second is content of cell. Content is centered and in italic font shape.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution with `makecell`, which allows for line breaks and a common formatting of cells in `l, r, c` columns, with the `\thead` and `\makecell` commands. The  default alignment is vertical  and horizontal  centring.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[top=1.2in,bottom=0.65in,left=1.15in,right=1.15in,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize\itshape}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{ccll}
  \toprule
  \thead{observed frequencies of\\each detection history} & \thead{detections\\ per site} & \thead[l]{equivalent detection histories ($h_i$)} & \thead[l]{probability} \\
  \midrule
  10& 4 &\texttt{1111}& $\psi p^4$\\
  20& 3 &\texttt{1110, 1101, 1011, 0111}& $\psi p^3(1-p)$\\
  30& 2 &\texttt{1100, 1001, 1010, 0011, 0101}& $\psi p^2(1-p)^2$\\
  20& 1 &\texttt{1000, 0100, 0010, 0001}& $\psi p(1-p)^3$\\
  20& 0 &\texttt{0000} & $\psi (1-p)^4 + (1-\psi)$\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\vspace{1cm}
\begin{center}
\renewcommand{\theadalign}{b}
  \begin{tabular}{ccll}
  \toprule
  \thead{observed frequencies of\\each detection history} & \thead{detections\\ per site} & \thead[l]{equivalent detection histories ($h_i$)} & \thead[l]{probability} \\
  \midrule
  10& 4 &\texttt{1111}& $\psi p^4$\\
  20& 3 &\texttt{1110, 1101, 1011, 0111}& $\psi p^3(1-p)$\\
  30& 2 &\texttt{1100, 1001, 1010, 0011, 0101}& $\psi p^2(1-p)^2$\\
  20& 1 &\texttt{1000, 0100, 0010, 0001}& $\psi p(1-p)^3$\\
  20& 0 &\texttt{0000} & $\psi (1-p)^4 + (1-\psi)$\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]